# Python - Change Value in Column based on Value in Same Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the following dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'TagCode':['A', 'B', 'A1', 'B1'],'Reading':[0,67,29,42]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

Dataframe

  TagCode  Reading
0       A        0
1       B        0
2      A1       29
3      B1       42
```

I want to achieve the following output where if in any instance where TagCode= A & Reading = 0, TagCode A1 Reading will be changed to 0.

Note Reading for TagCode B1 is unchanged despite TagCode B = 0.

```
Output
      TagCode  Reading
    0       A        0
    1       B        0
    2      A1        0
    3      B1       42
```

Comment: We're missing some assumptions here, does `if 0 in df.loc[df['TagCode'] == 'A', 'Reading']: df.loc[df['TagCode'] == 'A1', 'Reading'] = 0` do the trick?

Comment: So are you saying that all instances of A(n) will be changed to 0 if A is equal to 0?

Comment: @timgeb don't get me wrong but, is hardcode a necessary?

Comment: @OrkhanAliyev that's what I'm trying to figure out. OP's problem statement is extremely narrow, but I don't know if they realize that.

Comment: @timgeb, some people leave a piece of code as a trick and get lost. And asker assumes it's the best way to go. That's why I highlighted it.

Comment: OP here - apologies for the confusion but I believe @timgeb's comment is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Have you tried something yourself?

Answer (score 0):

My issue was solved by @timgeb in the comments using the following:

```
  if 0 in df.loc[df['TagCode'] == 'A', 'Reading']: df.loc[df['TagCode'] == 'A1', 'Reading'] = 0


Output
      TagCode  Reading
    0       A        0
    1       B        0
    2      A1        0
    3      B1       42
```